# Why am I Getting an Ambiguous Column name CountryID error message when trying to execute this SQL statement:

Tags: c#, sql

```
SELECT
    CD.CountryID, CD.GrossLimit, CD.UnsecuredLimit,
    SUM(LT1.Amount), SUM(LT1.Unsecured), (100*SUM(LT1.Unsecured) / CD.UnsecuredLimit) as PercOverCountryLimit
   FROM CountryDetail CD 
   INNER JOIN
    (
    SELECT CompanyName AS Company, CollateralSName as Collateral, SUM(Amount) AS Amount,  
           SUM(Usecured) AS Unsecured, LT.Date as Date, Max(LT.CountryID) as CountryID
        FROM Loanstotal LT
        WHERE YearMonth = @YearMonth
        GROUP BY CompanyName, CollateralSName, LT.Date
    ) LT1
   ON CD.CountryID = LT1.CountryID 
   GROUP BY CountryID, GrossLimit, UnsecuredLimit
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you're grouping by `CountryID` which is being returned by both tables: `CountryDetail` and your sub-query.  Change your `GROUP BY` to `GROUP BY CD.CountryID, GrossLimit, UnsecuredLimit`.

In fact, I think as a best practice you should change all your column references so they're qualified with the proper aliases:

`GROUP BY CD.CountryID, CD.GrossLimit, CD.UnsecuredLimit`